# Need a regular expression - disallow only zeros, allow zeros with other numbers

Tags: regex

I want to validate a string to meet the following patterns:

```
00;0 (disallow)
00;00 (disallow)
01;123 (disallow)
00;1
00; (disallow)
00;000000 (disallow)
00;1234567890123 (disallow)
00;123456789012
00;10
00;01
00;00001
00;00100
00;0202020
00;1000000
00;00100100
```

In general, the string should be `^00;\d{1,12}$` but how to eliminate unnecessary lines in the example above and resolve the necessary in one regex expression?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this regex:

```
^00;(?!0+$)\d{1,12}$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/PvoZHO/2)

**RegEx Details:**

- `^00;`: Match `00;` at start of line
- `(?!0+$)`: Negative lookahead to fail the match if we have all zeroes
- `\d{1,12}$`: Match 1 to 12 characters of any digit before end